# Can a script run with admin credentials and then get the active user username?

Tags: security, powershell, scripting

Got a script on a server that has to run on every users computer, the issue is that actually I've got the username/password encrypted and I need a way of getting the credentials (without prompt) from an administrator user to access the sql server so that the username and password don't get "Hardcoded" on the script and then get the username of the active user as a string (`$env:username`). I can use the `Run As` command on a batch file to get the first part done, but with my little experience can't get a safe solution to automatizing the entire task.
I'm using the `Invoke-SqlCmd` cmdlet to fetch the information on tables like this:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance $server -Username $credentials.getnetworkcredential().Username -Password $credentials.getnetworkcredential().Password -database $DB
```

The credentials there are the ones of the ADMIN user. I did encrypt the password, but it can get decrypted. So I need a way of using the credentials without storing them on a .txt or in the code.

Comment: I don't fully understand your scenario, but Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem |select username typically gets the currently logged in user.

Comment: if i understand you correctly you are looking for a way to use the admin credentials in your script without hardcoding? You can store a credential in ecnrypted form and then use it in your script. For an example have a look at this: https://www.interworks.com/blogs/trhymer/2013/07/08/powershell-how-encrypt-and-store-credentials-securely-use-automation-script

Comment: that is what I want to do, but those encrypted credentials can be decrypted with a PowerShell command. So I need something not to be stored on a .txt or hardcoded on the script.

Comment: Well if it cant be decrypted it cant be used, but its not like you can read out the password.

Comment: After looking at the link again it wasnt the best to post. But You should be able to encrypt a full pair of creds using the same approach

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully get what you're trying to do here, but I want to address a point about credentials in powershell.

```powershell
$cred = Get-Credential
$cred | Export-Clixml -Path C:\path\to\store\creds.xml
```

Doing this will store those credentials encrypted in the xml file.

```powershell
$cred = Import-Clixml -Path C:\path\to\store\creds.xml
```

This will read it back in from the file, in a usable form.

Your issue with this seems to be that it can be decrypted, which to me implies that you think that *anyone* could successfully read and decrypt the credentials, but that is not actually the case.

The credentials are encrypted using a key that is based on both the *user* and the *computer* on which they were encrypted. No other user will be able to read it, and it won't be readable by any user on another computer. This actually is fine if the script will always be run by the same user on the same computer. It breaks down when you've got multiple computers.

You can create encrypted strings with a key that is supplied using `ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key`, but then you're back to square one because you need to store the key somewhere.

If you want to try that approach, have a look at [Storing Passwords to Disk in PowerShell with Machine-key Encryption](https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/storing-passwords-to-disk-in-powershell-with-machine-based-encryption/).

You could also try to use `cmdkey` which is the credential manager, but you'll still have to pre-populate it on every machine, and if you're going to do that you might as well generate a stored credential file for each machine you run it on.

If you could break down your workflow a bit more clearly, it would be easier to figure out how you could safely store your credentials.